# Case sensitivity goes crazy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-sensitive

I have a database and I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Resource] WHERE Name LIKE 'ChinaApp%'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Resource] WHERE Name LIKE 'Chinaapp%'
```

This is returning 2 different counts:

[image: Counts]

The first thing that came to my mind is to check the case sensitivity. I checked the collation on the server level, the database level and the column level:

### Server level : Latin1_General_**CI**_AS

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
```

[image: Server level]

### Database level : Danish_Norwegian_**CI**_AS

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('Data Warehouse', 'Collation')
```

[image: Database level]

### Column level : Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Resource'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Name'
```

[image: Column level]

### Question :

What is going wrong with the query? The case sensitivity is disabled as proven before. Why the counts are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM [RESOURCE] WHERE Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE 'Chinaapp%'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS** is the issue! Thank you @realspirituals for the hint!

In this default collation I have, 'aa' is actually one single character. The last line in the following link explain it. `Å`, `å`, `AA`, `Aa` and `aa` are all the same.

[Collation chart for Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS](http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0406.1252.Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS.html)

The following queries now provide the correct result set (count):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Resource] WHERE Name LIKE 'ChinaApp%'
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Resource] WHERE Name LIKE 'Chinaapp%'
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: But `aA` is not. We had an issue where data was not lowercased when inserted, making `bAar` different from `baAr` in the database, but identical in the code, even though the collation was case insensitive.

Comment: I could imagine how much time was spent debugging :)