# LINQ OrderBy is not sorting correctly

Tags: c#, linq

I hope someone can prove me wrong here :)

If I do this:

```
List<string> a = new List<string> { "b", "c", "a", "aa" };
var b = a.OrderBy(o => o).ToList();
```

I would expect the result of 'b' to be:

```
a
aa
b
c
```

Instead, the result I get is:

```
a
b
c
aa
```

How can I get OrderBy to do a "correct" alphabetical sort?
Am I just plain wrong? :)

Comment: how is this not an alphabetical order?

Comment: For me also, you should add which culture you´re using.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You’re in the Danish culture, which treats `aa` as `å` and puts it after `ø` accordingly. You can pass a string comparer that acts differently to `OrderBy` to change that:

```
var b = a.OrderBy(o => o, StringComparer.InvariantCulture).ToList();
```

Comment: Good answer, however how did you conclude this?

Comment: How you came to know he is in Danish Culture?:P

Comment: @HimBromBeere: It had to be a culture thing, so I checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#Language-specific_conventions.

Comment: Just for the fun of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956099/case-sensitivity-goes-crazy

Answer (score 21):

Most likely a cultural thing. You could try this:

```
List<string> a = new List<string> { "b", "c", "a", "aa" };
var b = a.OrderBy(o => o, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Comment: Use `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` property of `StringComparer` for comparison rules based on **english**, but without any regional variations